# Vs Test Failing with 3 errors on Azure Dev Ops Running nUnitTest

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nunit, vstest

I'm using VsTest to run my nUnit test on azure dev ops and getting failures.  This runs fine on my local machine but not in the Azure DevOps Release.  Here is are errors i'm seeing from the log.  Its not giving me much to go off of to track what could be wrong.  I thought it might be something in my .runsettings file but this is the same file I use locally which is fine.  There are to data collectors that is used by my runsettings file that uses code coverage and the video recorder.  I dont know if this is what might be causing the test to fail.  If i do want to use that and that might be whats causing is is there a way to download these dlls for the server to use or does these get automatically downloaded with vs tool installer?

Here is the current Task

1. Copy Files to: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) - succeeds
2. Visual Studio Test Platform Installer - Installs VS 2017 - succeeds
3. VSTest - I choose test plan - 
     - Fails
   - select test platform to - Installed by Tools Installer
   - I select path to my .runsettings file
   - I give the override test run parameters 
   - I check Code coveraged enabled

here is the error i received

Unhandled exception : System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
TestExecution encountered unexpected failures System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Error: The process 'E:\Agent_work_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.170.1\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 3762504530

```
   2021-05-07T14:52:00.1569206Z QueryForTaskIntervalInMilliseconds: 3000
2021-05-07T14:52:00.1570380Z MaxQueryForTaskIntervalInMilliseconds: 10000
2021-05-07T14:52:00.1571576Z QueueNotFoundDelayTimeInMilliseconds: 3000
2021-05-07T14:52:00.1598093Z MaxQueueNotFoundDelayTimeInMilliseconds: 50000
2021-05-07T14:52:00.1606607Z ===========================================
2021-05-07T14:52:01.2928251Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2021-05-07T14:52:01.3427529Z Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2021-05-07T14:52:01.8892467Z TestExecutionHost.Execute: Registered TestAgent : 798 : VS2VST05-VS2VST05i-41
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9062609Z Provided settings file:
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9079246Z <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9079831Z <RunSettings>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9080157Z   <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9084373Z   <RunConfiguration>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9084552Z     <MaxCpuCount>1</MaxCpuCount>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9084824Z     <!-- Path relative to directory that contains .runsettings file-->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9085105Z     <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9085266Z 
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9085400Z     <!-- x86 or x64 -->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9085703Z     <!-- You can also change it from the Test menu; choose "Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects" -->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9086015Z     <TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9086158Z 
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9086337Z     <!-- Framework35 | [Framework40] | Framework45 -->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9086627Z     <TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework45</TargetFrameworkVersion>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9087680Z 
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9087850Z     <!-- Path to Test Adapters -->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9088095Z     <TestAdaptersPaths>%SystemDrive%\Temp\foo;</TestAdaptersPaths>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9088519Z     <!-- TestSessionTimeout was introduced in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 -->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9088858Z     <!-- Specify timeout in milliseconds. A valid value should be greater than 0 -->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9089157Z     <TestSessionTimeout>15000000</TestSessionTimeout>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9089420Z     <TreatNoTestsAsError>true</TreatNoTestsAsError>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9089626Z   </RunConfiguration>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9089822Z   <!-- Configurations for data collectors -->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9090027Z   <DataCollectionRunSettings>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9090210Z     <DataCollectors>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9090804Z       <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9091620Z         <Configuration>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9092022Z           <CodeCoverage>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9092187Z             <ModulePaths>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9092348Z               <Exclude>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9092562Z                 <ModulePath>.*CPPUnitTestFramework.*</ModulePath>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9092794Z               </Exclude>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9092955Z             </ModulePaths>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9093227Z             <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9093579Z             <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9093914Z             <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9094217Z             <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9094530Z             <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9094757Z           </CodeCoverage>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9094927Z         </Configuration>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9095114Z       </DataCollector>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9095793Z       <DataCollector uri="datacollector://microsoft/VideoRecorder/1.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder.VideoRecorderDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataCollection.VideoRecorder, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" friendlyName="Screen and Voice Recorder">
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9096694Z         <!--Video data collector was introduced in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 -->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9096989Z         <Configuration>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9097297Z           <!-- Set "sendRecordedMediaForPassedTestCase" to "false" to add video attachments to failed tests only -->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9097917Z           <MediaRecorder sendRecordedMediaForPassedTestCase="false"  xmlns="">        ​
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9098305Z             <ScreenCaptureVideo bitRate="512" frameRate="2" quality="20" />​
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9098560Z           </MediaRecorder>​
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9100157Z         </Configuration>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9100322Z       </DataCollector>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9100532Z       <DataCollector friendlyName="blame" enabled="True">
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9100746Z       </DataCollector>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9100925Z     </DataCollectors>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9101487Z   </DataCollectionRunSettings>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9101720Z   <!-- Parameters used by tests at run time -->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9101885Z   
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9102041Z   <!-- MSTest adapter -->
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9102188Z   <NUnit>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9102371Z     <InternalTraceLevel>Error</InternalTraceLevel>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9102554Z   </NUnit>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9102666Z 
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9102782Z </RunSettings>
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9393681Z Overriding UseVerifiableInstrumentation field to false in the runsettings file.
2021-05-07T14:52:01.9550200Z IsValidServiceResponse: Received None command..Service Workflow is not active
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0476240Z ##[error]Unhandled exception : System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0485692Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.DiagnosticsSettingsProcessor.ProcessSettings(XDocument settings)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0486290Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.CommonSettingsManager.UpdateCommonSettings(InputDataContract inputDataContract, SettingsModifier settingsModifier)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0486843Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.SettingsManager.UpdateSettingsAsRequired(InputDataContract inputDataContract)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0487361Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.SetupPhase.Run(ExecutionStateContext stateModelContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0487776Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0488008Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0488240Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0488490Z    at System.AggregateException.Handle(Func`2 predicate)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0488905Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.ExecutionStateModel.DistributedTestExecutionAgent.ExecuteCurrentPhase(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0489423Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.ExecutionStateModel.DistributedTestExecutionAgent.Execute(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0489864Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.ExecutionStateModel.DistributedTestExecutionAgent.Start()
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0490324Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.AgentExecutionHost.DistributedTestRunHost.InitializeAndStartExecutionHost(Boolean debugLogs)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0490784Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.AgentExecutionHost.DistributedTestRunHost.Execute(Boolean debugLogs)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0491382Z ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0491868Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.DiagnosticsSettingsProcessor.ProcessSettings(XDocument settings)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0492404Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.CommonSettingsManager.UpdateCommonSettings(InputDataContract inputDataContract, SettingsModifier settingsModifier)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0492953Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.SettingsManager.UpdateSettingsAsRequired(InputDataContract inputDataContract)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0493484Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.SetupPhase.Run(ExecutionStateContext stateModelContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0493867Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0494108Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
2021-05-07T14:52:02.0494260Z 
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1579135Z ##[error]TestExecution encountered unexpected failures System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1581938Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.DiagnosticsSettingsProcessor.ProcessSettings(XDocument settings)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1583067Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.CommonSettingsManager.UpdateCommonSettings(InputDataContract inputDataContract, SettingsModifier settingsModifier)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1584187Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.SettingsManager.UpdateSettingsAsRequired(InputDataContract inputDataContract)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1585236Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.SetupPhase.Run(ExecutionStateContext stateModelContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1587079Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1587869Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1588636Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1589413Z    at System.AggregateException.Handle(Func`2 predicate)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1590350Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.ExecutionStateModel.DistributedTestExecutionAgent.ExecuteCurrentPhase(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1591492Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.ExecutionStateModel.DistributedTestExecutionAgent.Execute(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1591974Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.ExecutionStateModel.DistributedTestExecutionAgent.Start()
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1593219Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.AgentExecutionHost.DistributedTestRunHost.InitializeAndStartExecutionHost(Boolean debugLogs)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1594214Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.AgentExecutionHost.DistributedTestRunHost.Execute(Boolean debugLogs)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1595156Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.AgentExecutionHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1596244Z ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1597231Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.DiagnosticsSettingsProcessor.ProcessSettings(XDocument settings)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1597806Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.CommonSettingsManager.UpdateCommonSettings(InputDataContract inputDataContract, SettingsModifier settingsModifier)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1607075Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.SettingsManager.UpdateSettingsAsRequired(InputDataContract inputDataContract)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1608570Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.SetupPhase.Run(ExecutionStateContext stateModelContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1609155Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1610029Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()<---
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1610221Z 
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1612560Z 
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1613028Z Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1614180Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.DiagnosticsSettingsProcessor.ProcessSettings(XDocument settings)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1614742Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.CommonSettingsManager.UpdateCommonSettings(InputDataContract inputDataContract, SettingsModifier settingsModifier)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1620575Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.SettingsManager.SettingsManager.UpdateSettingsAsRequired(InputDataContract inputDataContract)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1621740Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.VstestAdapter.SetupPhase.Run(ExecutionStateContext stateModelContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1622351Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1625627Z    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1626144Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1626519Z    at System.AggregateException.Handle(Func`2 predicate)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1627028Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.ExecutionStateModel.DistributedTestExecutionAgent.ExecuteCurrentPhase(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1627670Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.ExecutionStateModel.DistributedTestExecutionAgent.Execute(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1629545Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.ExecutionStateModel.DistributedTestExecutionAgent.Start()
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1630375Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.AgentExecutionHost.DistributedTestRunHost.InitializeAndStartExecutionHost(Boolean debugLogs)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1631959Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.AgentExecutionHost.DistributedTestRunHost.Execute(Boolean debugLogs)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1632811Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestService.AgentExecutionHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1866126Z ##[error]Error: The process 'E:\Agent\_work\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.170.1\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe' failed with exit code 3762504530
2021-05-07T14:52:02.1874141Z ##[section]Finishing: VsTest - testPlan
```

Here is the Yaml file

```
steps:
```

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  inputs:
  SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_Atlas Automation (Agile) CI 2020/drop/Atlas_Automation_Test/Atlas_Automation_Test/bin/Release'
  Contents: |
  *.testsettings
  *.runsettings
  TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  CleanTargetFolder: true
  OverWrite: true
  flattenFolders: true

Comment: Please share your yaml file with us, and it seems that the vstest task has some null variables and you have to check it carefully.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT I added the Yaml file.  I would also like to add that i did run this on another server and it gave me the same error message but complained about a missing file. Its stated this "  ##[warning]RunMessage : System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."was missing but it doesn't really makes sense, because i built my pipeline successfully & all the required dll in folder